# 404 error in ASP MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My folder structure looks like this:

```
main
 |
 ———site1
 |
 ———site2
 |
 ———site3
 |
 ———common
```

site1.com points to main/site1, site2.com points to main/site2, and site3.com points to main/site3. I am using IIS 6.

The main folder is an application that runs on the DefaultAppPool (.NET 2.0 framework). I created another app pool for the common folder so it now runs on .NET 4.0. I have configured the urls so that site1.com/common, site2.com/common, and site3.com/common would point to the common folder. It works perfectly for site1 and site2. However, it produces a 404 error (page not found) for site3. The only difference is that site1 and site2 use any of the unassigned ip addresses, while a static ip address is configured for site3.

What may be the cause of the 404 error on site3?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a security issue when you used static ip for site3. Create a virtual directory in site3 to locate common folder. It will allow you access common within site3.